# system.io.streamwriter on .net compact framework accents

Tags: c#, compact-framework, iostream, streamwriter

well i am using all these codes:

```
// StreamWriter file = new StreamWriter(AppSettings.Instance.Dpath + "\\notaventa.txt");

// StreamWriter file = new StreamWriter(AppSettings.Instance.Dpath + "\\notaventa.txt", false, System.Text.Encoding.GetEncoding(1252));
' Dim objEscritor = New StreamWriter("C:\temp\salida_encoding.txt", True, System.Text.Encoding.Default)
// StreamWriter file = new StreamWriter(AppSettings.Instance.Dpath + "\\notaventa.txt", true, System.Text.Encoding.ASCII);
```

but none work for print

> canción

everyone print

> canci?n

how can i fix it? i am using

> compact framework 3.5

for Hand helds

Answer (score 1, accepted):

ASCII does not include support for the `ó` character. Unless you have compelling reason otherwise, you should always use Unicode:

```
System.IO.StreamWriter file = new System.IO.StreamWriter(
    Path.Combine(AppSettings.Instance.Dpath, "notaventa.txt"), true, 
    System.Text.Encoding.UTF8);
```

Unrelated to your question: You should use `Path.Combine` (rather than explicit string concatenation) for constructing file paths. It would save you the headache of determining whether to include the leading/trailing `\` or not.

Comment: System.Text.Ecoding.UTF8 didn't work remember i am suing compact framework 3.5

Comment: `UTF8` _is_ supported by the .NET Compact Framework; check [Encoding Properties](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dxsf38kx%28v=vs.90%29).

Comment: ok i'll check again, it is on true, maybe for that it didn't work very good

Answer (score 2):

You can fix it by *not* specifying `Encoding.ASCII`. UTF-8 is usually a good bet, although of course it depends on what's going to *read* the file. Basically ASCII doesn't have *any* accented characters; it stops at U+007E.

I'd expect `Encoding.GetEncoding(1252)` to work though, as [Windows 1252](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Windows-1252) contains character "ó". Ditto the default when you don't specify an encoding, as that would use UTF-8. Are you sure your string contains the right data to start with? What are you using to *read* the file, too?